# Accelerate and bitsandbytes is needed to install but I did

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to load quantization like

```
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig

model = '/model/'
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model, quantization_config=BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_8bit=True))
```

but I get the error

```
ImportError: Using `load_in_8bit=True` requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes` or pip install bitsandbytes`
```

But I've installed both, and I get the same error. I shut down and restarted the jupyter kernel I was using this on.

Comment: Able to resolve this?

Comment: I made another virtual environment with python 3.11 (the one I was getting these errors with is 3.10), but get different errors, pertaining to a needed gpu, but not a mac gpu (which I have). So idk

Comment: But I still have the venv the errors here happened on if anyone has ideas to try, would be good to know in any case.

Comment: I get this issue both in a 3.11 environment and in a 3.10 environment, on macOS.  downgrading to `transformers==4.30` (from the default version 4.33) in the python 3.10 env seems to fix it for now.

Comment: Does this not happen on other OS?

Comment: I ran on macOS 14 with python 3.11 and it show `NO GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.`

Answer (score 28):

I downgraded `transformers` library to version 4.30 using the following command:

```
pip install transformers==4.30
```

Comment: Hi, Niels here from the Transformers team - downgrading your Transformers version is actually not the right solution, the error typically happens when you are running `load_in_4bit=True` or `load_in_8bit=True` on CPU. We now return a better error message stating that no GPU was found.

Comment: So the solution is to just not use it

Answer (score 10):

I am on a M1 Mac and also have similar problems. After installing `accelerate` and `bitsandbytes` I still get

> ImportError: Using `load_in_8bit=True` requires Accelerate: `pip install accelerate` and the latest version of bitsandbytes `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ bitsandbytes` or pip install bitsandbytes

I looked around a bit in the Transformers source code and found a function called `is_bitsandbytes_available()` which only returns true if bitsandbytes is installed **and** `torch.cuda.is_available()`, which is not the case on an Apple Silicon machine. Also, https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues/252 confirms that there is no MPS (Metal) support in bitsandbytes. I don't know why Huggingface's documentation doesn't mention (unless I've missed it somewhere) that their examples won't work on Apple Silicon.

Comment: I am trying to fine-tune a LLAMA model (or any LLM for that matter). Do you know which one I could use with my Mac M1? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EshitaShukla I'm sorry but that is beyond my current levels of ML knowledge (but something I'm also curious about).

Comment: Hi, `load_in_8bit=True` is only supported on GPUs which PyTorch supports (NVIDIA and AMD at the moment).

Answer (score 7):

I have tried everything above, nothing worked. After doing research, change the runtime to GPU and it will work. Worked for me.

[image: GPU]

Thank me later!

Comment: Jesus Christ! yes. This worked on Gcolab

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.
I was running falcon-7B in colab to fine-tune it.
First if I used transformers=4.30 as mentioned above and it solved the issue.

**But its for CPU running**: `change the environment to GPU`. and the issue will go away anyway.
**That is colab CPU and GPU uses different transformer version**.
And GPU does not need to downgrade during pip install.

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me, and my use case was quite similar, i.e. fine-tuning Falcon7B with mental health data on GC. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `accelerate` after installation. Please see this guide: https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/basic_tutorials/install#configuring--accelerate

In short:

```
python -c "from accelerate.utils import write_basic_config; write_basic_config(mixed_precision='fp16')"
```

Comment: I tried this from inside a Notebook using `!python -c...` to execute a shell command. I also tried running the code within the double quotes (`from accelerate.utils...`) within the notebook, and got the same error as before.

Comment: DId not work for me

Answer (score 0):

As @niels says in his comment:

> Hi, Niels here from the Transformers team - downgrading your Transformers version is actually not the right solution, the error typically happens when you are running load_in_4bit=True or load_in_8bit=True on CPU. We now return a better error message stating that no GPU was found.

So for me, when I downgraded transformers, I just got a keyerror relating to the model I was trying to bring in. When I commented out `load_in_4_bit=True`, things worked.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1", device_map="auto" #, load_in_4bit=True
)
```

I'm on [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/llm_tutorial) and hit a problem right after this line, but the model object appears to be fine.

Update: got everything to work on CPU. Just needed to remove the `.to("cuda")` calls from that tuturial.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm currently fine-tuning a model with Mistral LLM check GPU is available 1. torch.cuda.is_available() 2. check the compatability for cuda version with torch version

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works I found that reinstalling bitsandbytes worked

`pip install bitsandbytes`

I am really not sure why since the error is

`requires Accelerate: pip install accelerate`